# Is a bologna-process tag justified?

Tags: discussion, tags

There is a bunch of questions about the Bologna process on this SE, they tend to have rather broad tags:

[Israel and the Bologna Process](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/117957/100339) 
 
[phd](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/phd)[israel](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/israel)

[Post-Bologna process, is my sociology degree an undergraduate degree or a graduate degree?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/68063/100339) 
 [masters](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/masters)

[Are there any standard regulations for oral exams for universities in Bologna process?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/107851/100339) 
[exams](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/exams)

[Which authority establishes the equivalence of degrees from different European countries?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/97511/100339) 
 [master](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/master) [degree](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/degree)[europe](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/europe)[bachelor](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bachelor)[russia](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/russia)

They are notably not present in each other's "Related" section of the right panel. There are also a number of mentions of the Bologna process in answers to questions that do not mention it (see eg [this answer](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/73217/100339)).

I am planning on asking one too. Is [degree](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/degree)[europe](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/europe) enough? Or is the creation of [bologna-process](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bologna-process) justified?

Comment: A side note. We probably have two groups of users: those who care about tags and those, like me, who find tags virtually useless and consider caring about them a worthless effort. Given that discussions about tags attract few users, I suspect that the second group is much larger than the first one. I'm usually fine with the creation of any tag that makes the first group happy. That said, if you have a question about the Bologna process, just go on asking, tags can be added anyway later on.

Answer (score 1):

Go ahead and add the tag. You have a found a bunch of related questions and a tag is completely valid way of indicating that. The tag is about the substance of the questions and not a meta tag.

Comment: The asker doesn’t have enough reputation to create a new tag, but you do. Given that nobody objected in over a month, I see no problem with this.

Comment: I did it already.